# Python says my class has no __call__ method

Tags: python, class, methods, call, attributeerror

I'm completely stuck. Thought I've already understood classes, guess I was wrong :/ Anyway, my code looks like this:

```
class LinearRegression:

def __init__(self, x, y, full = 0):
    self.full = full
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __call__(self):
    squared_sum_x = (sum(self.x))**2 
    n = len(self.x)
    xx = sum([item**2 for item in self.x])
    xy = sum([xi*yi for xi, yi in zip(self.x,self.y)])
    a = 1.0*((n*xy -(sum(self.y)*sum(self.x)))/(n*xx - squared_sum_x))
    b = (sum(self.y) - a*sum(self.x))/n
    if self.full == 0:
        return (a,b)
    elif self.full == 1:
        squared_sum_y = (sum(self.y))**2
        yy = sum([item**2 for item in self.y])
        R = float((n*xy -(sum(self.y)*sum(self.x)))/(((n*xx - squared_sum_x)*(n*yy - squared_sum_y))**0.5))
        S_a = (1/(n-2))*((yy-(a*xy)-(b*sum(self.y)))/(xx-(n*xx)))
        S_b = S_a * (n*xx)
        return (a, b, R, S_a, S_b)
    else:
        return "full parameter must be 0, 1 or empty"

lr = LinearRegression(range(10),range(10,30,2),0)
lr()
```

And I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: LinearRegression instance has no __call__ method
```

Question is: why ? Because I've spent hours analysing this bit of code and have absolutely no idea what's wrong...

Comment: Is the formatting correct? As you surely know, indentation is important in Python.

Comment: And what does `dir(LinearRegression)` show is part of the class? You probably have indentation issues.

Comment: Thanks, it was formatting indeed, init was indented badly. I didn't check it before as it was a part of a prototype of this class written by my teacher - assumed the guy with Ph.D. in computer science wouldn't make such an error, guess I was wrong :P

Comment: As posted, your class wouldn't have `__init__` either. Please fix your indentation to show *exactly* what code you are running.

Comment: After indenting the two methods, works for me -- result `(2.0, 10.0)`. However without doing that I get an `IndentationError: expected an indented block` on the `def __init_():` line, which you should also have gotten.
`

Comment: Strangely, I didn't get any indentation errors, only 'AttributeError' as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is in your indentation. You're not actually including those methods in your class, since your indentation is placing them "outside". Try this instead:

```
class LinearRegression:

    def __init__(self, x, y, full = 0):
        self.full = full
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self):
        squared_sum_x = (sum(self.x))**2 
        n = len(self.x)
        xx = sum([item**2 for item in self.x])
        xy = sum([xi*yi for xi, yi in zip(self.x,self.y)])
        a = 1.0*((n*xy -(sum(self.y)*sum(self.x)))/(n*xx - squared_sum_x))
        b = (sum(self.y) - a*sum(self.x))/n
        if self.full == 0:
            return (a,b)
        elif self.full == 1:
            squared_sum_y = (sum(self.y))**2
            yy = sum([item**2 for item in self.y])
            R = float((n*xy -(sum(self.y)*sum(self.x)))/(((n*xx - squared_sum_x)*(n*yy - squared_sum_y))**0.5))
            S_a = (1/(n-2))*((yy-(a*xy)-(b*sum(self.y)))/(xx-(n*xx)))
            S_b = S_a * (n*xx)
            return (a, b, R, S_a, S_b)
        else:
            return "full parameter must be 0, 1 or empty"
```

This way the methods will be "inside" your class, as opposed to being independently defined functions.

Comment: If the OP was a direct copy, the interpreter would complain about an empty class (`IndentationError: expected an indented block`). So I think it's not the only cause.